# Crash when presenting a ViewController from modally presented ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

In our production app we do have crash reports on presenting a `ViewController` from a modally presented `ViewController.

We have a `BackgroundForegroundDelegate`. Whenever the app enters the background it'll present a Lockscreen on top of the current `ViewController`.

AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    backgroundForegroundDelegate?.applicationDidEnterBackground()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    backgroundForegroundDelegate?.applicationWillEnterForeground()
}
```

LockScreenViewController:

```
class LockScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        view.sendSubview(toBack: blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

The `TabBarController`, which is the backgroundForegroundDelegate, will do the following to present that LockScreen:

```
lazy var lockScreenViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LockScreenViewController")

func applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    let visibleViewController = (self.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController)?.visibleViewController
    (visibleViewController as? BackgroundForegroundDelegate)?.applicationDidEnterBackground()

    lockScreenViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    if let modalVC = window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        // HERE it does crash
        modalVC.present(lockScreenViewController, animated: false,
                        completion: nil)
    } else {
        window.rootViewController!.present(lockScreenViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I marked the line where the crashs occured.

We couldn't reproduce it on the same phone with the same OS.

What can go wrong here and how can we make it "safe"?

---

Crash Report:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             MyApp [13594]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/**/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          *hidden*
Version:             1565 (1.2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           *hidden*


Date/Time:           2017-09-24 14:46:10.5972 +0200
Launch Time:         2017-09-24 14:43:55.8968 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A372)
Baseband Version:    4.00.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18261fd38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x181b34528 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   UIKit                           0x18bda189c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4828 (UIViewController.m:6945)
3   UIKit                           0x18bda4074 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 68 (UIViewController.m:7453)
4   UIKit                           0x18ba3ca84 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104 (UIView.m:11718)
5   UIKit                           0x18bda3fc8 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 220 (UIViewController.m:7451)
6   UIKit                           0x18bda4488 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 528 (UIViewController.m:7531)
7   UIKit                           0x18bda3ea4 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 188 (UIViewController.m:7462)
8   UIKit                           0x18bb0e55c -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 160 (UIViewController.m:7475)
9   MyApp                   0x1041794cc _T013MyApp24TabBarControllerC29applicationDidEnterBackgroundyyF + 472 (TabBarController.swift:81)
10  MyApp                   0x10417ace8 _T013MyApp24TabBarControllerCAA28BackgroundForegroundDelegateA2aDP019applicationDidEnterG0yyFTW + 20 (TabBarController.swift:0)
11  MyApp                   0x104151aa0 _T013MyApp11AppDelegateC29applicationDidEnterBackgroundySo13UIApplicationCFTo + 192 (AppDelegate.swift:76)
12  UIKit                           0x18bc9b648 __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 180 (UIApplication.m:6096)
13  UIKit                           0x18bd9e338 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128 (UIViewController.m:6538)
14  UIKit                           0x18bc9b538 -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 104 (UIApplication.m:6088)
15  UIKit                           0x18bf2531c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability deactivateEventsOnly:withContext:forceExit:completion:] + 860 (_UICanvasLifecycleMonitor.m:375)
16  UIKit                           0x18c68d760 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 380 (_UIApplicationCanvas.m:0)
17  UIKit                           0x18c68d58c -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448 (_UIApplicationCanvas.m:156)
18  UIKit                           0x18c4099c0 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220 (_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:210)
19  UIKit                           0x18c59efc8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112 (_UICanvasSettingsDiffAction.m:34)
20  UIKit                           0x18c409870 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252 (_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:181)
21  UIKit                           0x18c1f3850 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364 (_UICanvas.m:517)
22  UIKit                           0x18c098bd8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 468 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:77)
23  FrontBoardServices              0x184cc221c __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.362 + 212 (FBSSceneImpl.m:571)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x181fa5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x181fac6c8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288 (queue.c:3025)
26  FrontBoardServices              0x184cf5a04 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36 (FBSSerialQueue.m:164)
27  FrontBoardServices              0x184cf56a8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404 (FBSSerialQueue.m:196)
28  FrontBoardServices              0x184cf5c44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:232)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x1825c8358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x1825c82d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x1825c7b60 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x1825c5738 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
33  CoreFoundation                  0x1824e62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
34  GraphicsServices                0x184377f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
35  UIKit                           0x18ba92880 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:3948)
36  MyApp                   0x1040c100c main + 56 (ContactsService.swift:16)
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x18200a56c start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182139348 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224d354 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001820a8fd8 abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b0c068 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:75)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b0c210 default_terminate_handler() + 304 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:68)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181b34810 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:657)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b2454c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b245b8 std::terminate() + 60 (cxa_handlers.cpp:97)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fa505c _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:505)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fac6c8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288 (queue.c:3025)
10  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184cf5a04 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36 (FBSSerialQueue.m:164)
11  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184cf56a8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404 (FBSSerialQueue.m:196)
12  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184cf5c44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:232)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c8358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c82d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c7b60 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c5738 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824e62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184377f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
19  UIKit                           0x000000018ba92880 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:3948)
20  MyApp                   0x00000001040c100c main + 56 (ContactsService.swift:16)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018200a56c start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118a3c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824e62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182f0e6e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182f2dafc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018c5de02c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:422)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018300f860 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224c32c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224c1f8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac38 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118a3c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824e62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182f0e6e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182f6062c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:389)
7   MyApp                   0x00000001041c7330 +[GAI threadMain:] + 64 (GAI.m:228)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018300f860 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224c32c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224c1f8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac38 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182139dbc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224afb0 _pthread_wqthread + 884 (pthread.c:0)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac30 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac2c start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2447)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac2c start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2447)

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118a3c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fbacf4 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 644 (mach.c:831)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fbb19c dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$mp + 56 (mach.c:1958)
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001822879cc xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 196 (connection.c:802)
5   BaseBoard                       0x0000000184aed634 -[BSXPCMessage sendSynchronouslyToConnection:error:] + 76 (BSXPCMessage.m:189)
6   BaseBoard                       0x0000000184ae9dac -[BSBaseXPCClient _sendMessage:withReplyHandler:waitForReply:waitDuration:] + 320 (BSBaseXPCClient.m:233)
7   AssertionServices               0x0000000184b3cc10 -[BKSAssertionClientMultiplexer sendEvent:withAssertionType:forEventType:responseHandler:] + 272 (BKSAssertionClientMultiplexer.m:87)
8   AssertionServices               0x0000000184b36a98 -[BKSProcessAssertionClient sendCreateEvent:error:] + 116 (BKSProcessAssertionClient.m:53)
9   AssertionServices               0x0000000184b3a4c8 -[BKSAssertion _clientQueue_acquireAssertion] + 136 (BKSAssertion.m:293)
10  AssertionServices               0x0000000184b3a0fc __45-[BKSAssertion _registerAssertionAndAcquire:]_block_invoke + 80 (BKSAssertion.m:235)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fa5088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fa5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181faee48 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528 (inline_internal.h:2500)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181faf7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340 (queue.c:5302)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fb0200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400 (queue.c:5920)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181fb84a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644 (source.c:2515)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224afe0 _pthread_wqthread + 932 (pthread.c:2207)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac30 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac2c start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2447)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182118a3c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825c58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824e62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182c4fb40 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404 (NSURLConnection.mm:367)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018300f860 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224c32c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224c1f8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018224ac38 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001c42ea5b7
    x4: 0x0000000181b29afd   x5: 0x000000016bd425a0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000018225163c  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x00000001820bf557  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000000ffffffff  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b2fe3b80  x21: 0x000000016bd425a0  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b2fe3c60
   x24: 0x0000000000002403  x25: 0x0000000000002303  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001c41fc808   fp: 0x000000016bd42500   lr: 0x000000018224d354
    sp: 0x000000016bd424d0   pc: 0x0000000182139348 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: can you provide any crash log?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ give me a minute, i have to "anonymise" some things before i can post the crash report.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ added the crash report

Comment: Can you provide me a photo of the entire `TabBarController.swift` that include line numbers? If it is too long then just focus on lines 0 and 81.

Comment: @AnhPham the line 81 is the marked `modalVC.present(lockScreenViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)` Line 0 is not existent  but line 1 is `import UIKit`. I assume that it might be an issue that it might present a VC when there is already one presented from that VC. But that doesn't produce any crash when done locally.

Comment: @AnhPham I am not allowed to post the full TabBarController. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I need to present multiple modals I end up using `addChildViewController()` to add the vc's.

The I'm animating the childViewController.view in from the bottom edge of the screen to immitate the systems modal presentation animation.

If you want to use the systems present() method make sure you really present on the top most view controller.